# How to exclude directories/files from Meteor's bundler

Tags: javascript, meteor

Meteor watches the current project's directory for file changes so that it can automatically restart the server.

As my project grew in size, I noticed that the time it takes for each "refresh" has gone up from ~1 seconds to 8+ seconds.

I'm looking to exclude some files and directories, and I'm wondering if I should edit app/lib/bundler.js or if there's a better way.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you editing a live bundled meteor app (created with meteor bundle xxx)? Is it you editing the files or changes to the file system by your app (e.g file uploads)?

Comment: add ~ to the end of folder like models~, it will treat as static ?

Comment: Sry, I'm not editing a live bundled meteor app. Just developing with the meteor cmd. I think i was confused with another answer, so editing bundler.js is not the way to go.

Comment: @crapthings Thanks for the tip. It works! It does exclude the ("~" suffix'ed) folder completely from the project. So I need to remember to remove the "~" later on. Anyway, I'll accept your answer. =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bundler (`tools/bundler.js`) has a list of regexps that it ignores:

```
// files to ignore when bundling. node has no globs, so use regexps
var ignore_files = [
    /~$/, /^\.#/, /^#.*#$/,
    /^\.DS_Store$/, /^ehthumbs\.db$/, /^Icon.$/, /^Thumbs\.db$/,
    /^\.meteor$/, /* avoids scanning N^2 files when bundling all packages */
    /^\.git$/ /* often has too many files to watch */
];
```

Another approach is to place the files in a `test` directory. Unless you request to bundle tests, this is excluded.

One final approach is is to put files under the `packages` directory. I don't think you even need to have a stub `package.js` file.

Both of these options are a little bit hacky, but perfectly serviceable.

I think it would be nice if there was something like `.meteorignore` akin to `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thanks, I was having a bit trouble trying to find bundler.js. Now i've got it. It's under tools/ in the meteor git repository.

Comment: An alternative I used was to move the meteor app into `app/` and have `bower_components` as a sibling. The `RTD` testing framework asks for the same setup.

Answer (score 12):

Another way is to prefix folders you want to exclude with a period.

Comment: Great solution if you want the whole folder hidden say at the root like a .tmp or .bak folder