# How do I make text files accessible to the server on Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm surprised I can't google my answer here... it seems no one else is having the issue.

When you run the meteor service the js, html, etc. is packaged in the .meteor/local/build folder, but it appears to exclude stuff that isn't js or html. I have a folder called "magicsets" and one called "magicimgs" and neither are in the /local/build folder. This is obviously why, when i attempt to use fs to readfile, it fails to find the file "magicsets/M14.json"

I tried putting the magicsets folder into a folder named "private", but that didn't accomplish anything.

How do I make files accessible locally to my server via FS and how do I make files accessible publically to my server via raw urls?

I'm sure I'm missing something very simple, because there are lots of more complicated questions and answers on SO, yet there is no answer for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Meteor 0.6.5 which was released yesterday has a new feature which helps loads with this.

Make a directory called `/private` which you can access with the new [Assets.getText](http://docs.meteor.com/#assets_getText) or [Assets.getBinary](http://docs.meteor.com/#assets_getBinary) functions.

The stuff in the `/private` directory will then be bundled up into a directory called `assets` in `/program/server/assets` and it will not be accessible to the web & you wouldn't need to worry about using `fs` either. You could just use `Assets.getText` instead

To make a publicly accessible file put it in `/public`. So if you had `a.jpg` at `/public/a.jpg` it would be accessible at http://yourdomain.com/a.jpg

Comment: I never tried the public thing yet, but I got stuck on the private folder and thought maybe I misunderstood everything. I think the key I was missing was the assets class. Thanks, I'll try this in a bit reply after trying it.

Comment: That worked well. Thanks a lot :). I really hope they improve the Meteor documentation soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you want text files to be available to the webserver i.e. the server that defaults to port 3000, create a folder called `public` in the root of the project/app directory.  drop your folder and files there. You would then be able to access them  as `http://localhost:3000/magicsets/M14.json`

update: it looks like can override the bundler, but it does require changing some of the core code there's no .meteorignore file yet. check this SO answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16742853/105282

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a server-side method, but this was useful info as well.

Answer (score 1):

To serve a directory of files publicly independent of what Meteor is doing, you can use the following approach. I do this, for example, when I need to link an entire (Javascript) git repo into my Meteor app so I can work on a checked out version of the library.

The following works for 0.6.5. It basically servers up a checked out folder of [OpenLayers](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers) in `/lib`:

```
connect = Npm.require('connect')

RoutePolicy.declare('/lib', 'network')

WebApp.connectHandlers
  .use(connect.bodyParser())
  .use('/lib', connect.static("/home/mao/projects/openlayers/lib"))
```

For more information, see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1229.