# Add static file to meteor app while deployed on server

Tags: nginx, meteor

I want to add a set of static files to my meteor app; it's currently deployed to an nginx + ubuntu server as described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-meteor-js-application-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-nginx).  When I simply add the static file to the app and execute `restart appname`, it doesn't work (the 404 page is displayed instead of the file), while files which were already deployed work fine.

However, when I re-build my entire app and restart the app on the server, the static files are served appropriately.  Why?  Does it have to be this hard?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on whether or not you want your static files to be publicly available, you should do one of two things when setting up your application. Put assets only accessible by your application on the server and not accessible to the rest of the world within the `private` top-level directory in your application. Once these are bundled into your application, they will appear in the directory `/program/server/assets`. If you want files to be accessible to the world on the client, put them in the `public` top-level directory in your application. These files will be available from the top level of your website (www.example.com/examplefile.jpg).

As for whether or not you should rebuild your application when attempting to deploy new static files in your application, it is best to allow Meteor to properly bundle everything as necessary into the application rather than trying to add files to your application directly.

For additional information, please see the Meteor documentation [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/assets_getText) or check out this SO question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247543/how-do-i-make-text-files-accessible-to-the-server-on-meteor).