# How to exclude files from Meteor's generation of app?

Tags: meteor, bower

Tl;dr : Is there an equivalent in meteor to .gitignore?

Yes, I am aware of using a leading '.' in the directory name to get meteor to exclude it. But using leading dot is not a solution in this case. Read below to understand.

Longer:

I would like to use Bower.io to install various browser plugins.

Ideally, I run bower in the client subdirectory. Bower does its thing creating the bower_components directory and pulls down the plugin (pick a random jquery plugin for example).

Many plugins include example html, demo css files, etc. to show how to use the plugin.

Unfortunately, Meteor wants to include all that stuff in the application. Which unsurprisingly causes problems.

My current solution is to have bower.io run in the project's parent directory. This is not ideal as I have to copy js/css files over from the bower directory to the meteor client directory. (yes, I could use soft links but then the files would be missing when pushing to production).

With only a few client plugins / css packages this is becoming quite annoying.

NOTE: Renaming files/directories retrieved by bower.io to have a leading '.' or using bower in a dotted subdirectory helps only marginally. I would then have to manually include the files needed.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use Bower? Meteor's file management should be able to do everything you need. Your files will automatically get served to the client, and they should be minified/concatenated in production.

Comment: Not all javascript packages are in meteor's package system.

Comment: Yes but it is fairly simple to create a package with Meteorite. https://atmosphere.meteor.com/wtf/package

Comment: @Cuberto - I am not going to spend any time learning something, figuring out odd error messages, etc that I don't have to. You may be all into that sort of thing - I am not. Lots of other more interesting/higher value things to learn. I appreciate meteor but I am not going to exert effort I don't need to. Not being paid to learn meteor - being paid to get the product done.

Comment: That's fine, I'm just saying it would probably be faster to use Meteorite than to try and retrofit an incompatible package manager.

Comment: @Cuberto - Sure my preference is to use meteorite, but I am not going to make meteorite work if bower works for the library in question.

Answer (score 3):

Is this possibly a duplicate of [How to exclude directories/files from Meteor's bundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644780/how-to-exclude-directories-files-from-meteors-bundler)?

If you want to define the way you name your files, you could try including a certain regex to match in the meteor bundler. Otherwise, maybe it's something that needs to be implemented on a framework level.

I also found this tutorial by Tri on integrating meteor and bower: http://tridnguyen.com/articles/meteor-and-bower/. Tri defines a new meteor package to specify the exact files required on the client.

The best solution, however, is move away from Bower as Meteor offers its own package manager at a framework level. Including the front end files that you need using Meteor packages would be the more productive solution in the long run, especially as the framework changes.

Comment: Not all needed packages are in meteor. Meteor itself admits this with the acknowledgement that npm is needed to get many javascript packages not directly handled by meteor. ( And no it is not a duplicate, as the provided answer for that question uses dotted file names which I have stated is not useful for this problem.)

Comment: @Pat "Meteor itself admits this with the acknowledgement that npm is needed to get many javascript packages not directly handled by meteor." - You can use Meteorite packages to import NPM modules.

Comment: @justswim - the linked blog post looks like what I need. wrt meteorite, that blog post says it all: "However, depending on those packages add a layer of delay into your workflow, as updates will not be as quick as the original. This was true for me back in September when I wanted to use Bootstrap 3 as it was released to the public. Meteor did not have support for it until much later."