# How to make Meteor ignore files?

Tags: meteor

Is there some specific folder in Meteor file structure which is simply ignored by Meteor? (`meteor bundle` and `meteor deploy` etc)

Or better yet: is there a kind of `.meteorignore` file where we can list files for Meteor to ignore?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There's no such file as `.meteorignore` yet.

Currently the only reliable way to hide a file from Meteor is to make it hidden (add a dot to the beginning of name). You can hide the whole directory, which is useful if you need specific filenames for things like Grunt tasks.

For example if you create a directory called `.hammerTime`, then Meteor can't touch this.

**Update:**
As of Meteor v1.5.2.1, there is support for a `.meteorignore` file. It works exactly the same as a `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thanks. I've just created a PR for it: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/2172

Comment: This would be useful. Good luck with the PR!

Comment: BTW, I hadn't seen the duplicates when I asked the question. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16742853/370290) helped me on the way to the PR... You can +1 the PR if you like...

Comment: so, is there a way to customize the build at all?

Comment: Please check @Lucbug answer. Meteor has been updated supporting this feature.

Answer (score 14):

As of [Meteor v1.5.2.1](https://docs.meteor.com/changelog.html#v152120170926), there is support for a `.meteorignore` file. It works exactly the same as a `.gitignore`.

You can use them in any directory of your project and are fully integrated with the file watching system.

Comment: i added .meteorignore with entry somefolder/ but when a file is written in this folder, meteor keeps restarting

Comment: i am on meteor 1.5.2.2

Comment: Are you using the same pattern syntax as [.gitignore files](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)?

Comment: Been awhile, but i am sure i did it like gitignore files

Comment: @Gobliins or anyone you have to add folder with slash like `/dummy` instead of `dummy`