# Exclude files from auto-rebuilding meteor

Tags: meteor, emacs, eslint, flycheck

I'm building an app in Meteor, and am a big fan the auto-rebuild action, that listens to any file change, rebuilds the app and refreshes my browser. However, I recently started to use flycheck with eslint and flycheck creates a temporary files called `flycheck_my-module.js` in the current directory whenever I make a change in a file (as opposed to only on save). Meteor sees these files being created and rebuilds and reloads. This causes a lot of action and is heavy for my browser and ruining my workflow.

I can customize the prefix for for these files f.x. to `.#flycheck_` and that will make Meteor ignore them, however that will break the eslint checker.

So my question is. Is there any way to tell meteor to prevent all files starting with `flycheck_` from triggering a rebuild, something like `meteor run --ignore "flycheck_*.js"`.

Comment: Closely related although it requires to change the name of the file (thus not a duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802923/how-to-make-meteor-ignore-files

Answer (score 0):

Meteor handles the whole build process, so introducing something like flycheck isn't really ideal (same goes for transpilers, etc).

One possibility is to save those files inside the `test` folder, which is ignored by meteor. If the file is required to be in the same folder, you could quickly edit the source of flycheck to look in `'test/' + currentDir` & recreate the same folder structure within the `test` folder. Not really ideal, but that's about your only option if you want to keep using flycheck + emacs.

Comment: While not ideal in that case (since the proposed solution to the problem is kind of not to run into the problem in the first place), this would be a very good answer to the question I linked in the comment, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802923/how-to-make-meteor-ignore-files : The asker is specifically looking for an ignored folder!