# meteor - don't reload page when some folder changes

Tags: meteor

How is it possible to set up meteor so that it would not reload page when some folder changes. In my application users upload files and they saved to a public folder and each time this happens, meteor will reload pages in browser. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Closely related, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802923/how-to-make-meteor-ignore-files

Comment: @Kyll - the answer from that question - to add a dot to the beginning of folder name - is not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This will stop client and public folder changes from being *"hot code pushed"* to the browser, but also any further bundlings by your server (your app is compiled and served once):

```
meteor --once
```

Other than that, I don't even know where to start to explain you how much of a bad practice is to let users save data on the "public" directory.

EDIT: Only if you are interested in changing your code into a better practice, check out these options:

1. https://doctorllama.wordpress.com/2014/11/06/meteor-upload-package-with-jquery-file-upload/ look for point #2
2. the best there is https://atmospherejs.com/edgee/slingshot