# How can I exclude certain node_modules from Meteor's client side bundle?

Tags: meteor, npm, babeljs

With npm being the recommended packaging system as of [Meteor 1.3](https://guide.meteor.com/atmosphere-vs-npm.html), I now have both server-side and client-side packages in my `node_modules` directory. Meteor attempts to bundle all of these into one huge `modules.js` file.

The only way to get meteor to completely ignore files appears to be to change the file or directory name ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23802923/how-to-make-meteor-ignore-files?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644780/how-to-exclude-directories-files-from-meteors-bundler)).

But I don't want to completely ignore the files - Some modules I need only on the server side, some only on the client side.

Is there a way to get Meteor to only include certain node modules in the client side bundle, perhaps through creative naming or hacking `.babelrc`?

Comment: Since version 1.3, Meteor has a decent modules system and you can `import ...` whatever you want with the new ES6 syntax ([read here](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#es2015-modules)). Since everything is "opt-in" now there's no need to "out-out" anything.

Comment: @apendua is right but I found you need a bit of a tricky pattern to prevent Meteor from finding imports in server-only code and bundling them to the client. Basically, Meteor doesn't respect run-time conditionals testing `Meteor.isServer` so you need to hide things in "server" folders.

Answer (score 0):

Everything needs to go into the bundle, which you place on the server. When you go to your web site, the server makes your HTML, CSS and JS available and is loaded into  the browser. Only the node modules needed by your browser get loaded.

There is no need to do this :)

Comment: The module.js is loading things that I think I'm only using on the server side. For example, Winston logging, which is a server side logging package.

Comment: No, everything does not need to go into the bundle. And yes, there is a need to do this. For example, you might use many npm modules to do exclusively server-side work like rendering email templates and sending them, communicating with your payment gateway, generating PDFs, etc. In my case, this accounted for 2MB of javascript being sent to the client for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Hide them in *server* folder and import them indirectly.

To exclude certain npm *node_modules* from being bundled into the massive *modules.js* file and prevent useless megabytes of script being sent to the client: conditionally `require` a file that itself `imports` modules from within a *server* folder.

Like so:

```
/* /my-import-file.js */

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  module.exports = require('./server/server-only-file');
}
```

And the file that actually imports your large, useless-on-the-client npm modules:

```
/* /server/server-only-file.js */

// Import some modules that will NOT be sent to the client
import mailgun from 'mailgun.js';
import cheerio from 'cheerio';
import juice from 'juice';

export { juice, cheerio, mailgun };
```

Your other code can then do like so:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import myImport from '/my-import-file'

if(Meteor.isServer){
  myImport.doServerOnlyStuff();
}
```